# Finding $P(1)$, why do options say that I'm wrong?

Tags: polynomials

> A polynomial $P(x)$ has the leading coefficent of $1$ and is second degree
>   polynomial. $2+i$ makes $P(x)$ zero. Polynomial $P(x)$ has real coefficients Find $P(1)$

So we know that conjugate of complex root will be the other root. Hence,

$$P(x) = \alpha (x-(2+i))(x-(2-i))$$

And we're told that the leading coefficient is $1$, which means $\alpha = 1$

$$P(x) = (x-(2+i))(x-(2-i)) = x^2 -4x+5$$

$$P(1) = 2$$

However, the answer key says that I'm wrong. I can only see $3,5,6,10,12$ on options.

Comment: I presume there is an implicit assumption that the polynomial has real coefficients.

Comment: @Wojowu Exactly! Polynomial has real coefficients. It is stated in question.

Comment: In my opinion your answer is correct. So, probably there is a typo in the answer key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

Perhaps the question had a typo and should have asked for $P(-1)$, which would be $10$ (?) but this is just a guess.